# How to use scientific notation in js?

Tags: javascript, math

```
var a = 5.0;
var b = a * 10e-12;
b *= 10e+12
print(b)
```

[Why b equals 500 instead of 5?](http://ideone.com/Ne6ZJ1)

As far as I know 10^(-12) equals to 1/(10^12), how can i rewrite the code?

Comment: actually. 10e12 is 1e13

Comment: So stupid mistake, thank you all for clarification.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because math. `10e1` is `100` and `10e-1` is `1`.

- `10e1 * 10e-1` is `100`.
- `10e2 * 10e-2` is `100`.
- `10e3 * 10e-3` is `100`.

You can *very easily* extend this to figure out that `10eN * 10e-N` is always going to be `100`.

If you want actual scientific notation, as in `1 * 10 ^ 2`, you want `1e12` and `1e-12`.

Answer (score 13):

10<sup>-12</sup> × 10<sup>12</sup> = 1

But what you wrote wasn't 10<sup>-12</sup>, nor did you write 10<sup>12</sup>.

What you wrote was 10 × 10<sup>12</sup> and 10 × 10<sup>-12</sup>:

10 × 10<sup>12</sup> × 10 × 10<sup>-12</sup> = 100

100 × 5 = 500

Proper scientific notation is `1e-12` and `1e12`. The `e` stands for "ten to the power of", so you don't need to multiply that value by ten again.

Answer (score 2):

"As far as I know 10^(-12) equals to 1/(10^12)" -- that is correct, but
`10e-12` actually means 10*10^(-12)