# Cookies expiration time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, session-cookies

I have javascript code that sets cookies expiration time once per session. Can anyone explain what does this part of code means? In particular: + days * 864e+5). I'd like to set a cookie to expire after 24hours.

```
if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
   var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
   t.setMilliseconds(t.getMilliseconds() + days * 864e+5);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: how many millseconds are there in a day? 1000*60*60*24=......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use scientific notation in js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151311/how-to-use-scientific-notation-in-js)